# Laravel horizon separate connection for metadata

Tags: php, laravel, redis, horizon

In `horizon.php line 42`:

```
/*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Horizon Redis Connection
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the name of the Redis connection where Horizon will store the
    | meta information required for it to function. It includes the list
    | of supervisors, failed jobs, job metrics, and other information.
    |
    */

    'use' => 'connectionA',
```

this is use to save all the metadata for job, and let say i have 2 connection which is connection A and B, how do i save the metadata in connection A and connection B?
from this config it seems can only save all the metadata in 1 connection only.
How do i separate it for every connection?

**What I want to achieve:**

```
SwiftDoJob::dispatch($logId)->onConnection('connectionA')->onQueue('queueA'); // how to make this will save the metadata to connection A?

SwiftDoJob::dispatch($logId)->onConnection('connectionB')->onQueue('queueB'); // how to make this will save the metadata to connection B?
```